# Google Analytics incorrectly reporting traffic source as (direct) / (none)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have 2 websites, a marketing(Mar) site and a subscription management(SM) site, recently I have been tasked to implement GA on the SM site.

Initial implementation went fine and sending some custom pageviews worked nicely to help with our single page sign up form.

Traffic from the MAR site gets dropped directly into our subscribe process when someone clicks buy and we have multiple sites on the domain separated by country, url's end like /uk/car, /fr/motorcycle, etc

I was expecting to see these urls in the Source section of GA but I see a very large proportion of the traffic sources as (direct)/(none) 87% in fact and no entries at all for any of the MAR site urls.

I have checked the referer in the headers manually and can see that the URL is infact correct when you land in the SM site.

The only thing I can think of is that the MAR site, also has a tracker in my SM site so that they can see our subscribe process in their stats and that maybe GA is considering them to be the same site.

They are hosted in completely different servers.

I would love some help on this, I am very new to GA myself as are my colleagues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Probably your marketing site is included in the referral exclusion list, but I concur that this is not on-topic.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks that is what the issue was.